# Interactively change glyphs in bokeh plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

I'm trying to generate a bokeh application which allows the user to change the glyphs of a plot. Unfortunately, the glyphs don't change after calling on_change() method of the dropdown button although I'm able to change the axis label in a similar way. However, changing plot.glyph outside of the called function works fine.

```
from bokeh.layouts import layout
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import Dropdown
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models.markers import Cross, Circle

source=ColumnDataSource(dict(x=[1,2,3],y=[4,5,6]))

fig=figure()
plot=fig.circle(x='x', y='y',source=source)
fig.xaxis.axis_label='This is a label'

#this changes the glyphs from circle to cross
plot.glyph=Cross(x='x', y='y', size=20, line_color='firebrick',
fill_color='firebrick', line_alpha=0.8, fill_alpha=0.3)

def update_plot(attr,old,new):
    if dropdown.value=='cross':
        #this changes the axis label but not the glyphs
        fig.xaxis.axis_label='Label changed'
        plot.glyph=Cross(x='x', y='y', size=20, line_color='firebrick',
        fill_color='firebrick', line_alpha=0.8, fill_alpha=0.3)
    elif dropdown.value=='circle':
        #this also only changes the axis label but not the glyphs
        fig.xaxis.axis_label='Label changed again'
        plot.glyph=Circle(x='x', y='y', size=20, line_color='firebrick',
        fill_color='firebrick', line_alpha=0.8, fill_alpha=0.3)

menu=[('Circle','circle'),('Cross', 'cross')]
dropdown=Dropdown(label="Select marker", menu=menu, value='circle')
dropdown.on_change('value', update_plot)

lay_out=layout([fig, dropdown])

curdoc().add_root(lay_out)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about the exact reasons why your approach doesn't work, but this one works:

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import layout
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import Dropdown
from bokeh.plotting import figure

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]))

plot = figure()

renderers = {rn: getattr(plot, rn)(x='x', y='y', source=source,
                                   **extra, visible=False)
             for rn, extra in [('circle', dict(size=10)),
                               ('line', dict()),
                               ('cross', dict(size=10)),
                               ('triangle', dict(size=15))]}


def label_fn(item):
    return 'Select marker ({})'.format(item)


menu = [('No renderer', None)]
menu.extend((rn.capitalize(), rn) for rn in renderers)

dropdown = Dropdown(label=label_fn(None), menu=menu, value=None)


def update_plot(attr, old, new):
    dropdown.label = label_fn(new)
    for renderer_name, renderer in renderers.items():
        renderer.visible = (renderer_name == new)


dropdown.on_change('value', update_plot)

lay_out = layout([plot, dropdown])

curdoc().add_root(lay_out)
```

Basically, I create all necessary renderers beforehand, and then just switch `visible` flag of each one.

Also, note the correct terminology. What you're calling a plot, is not actually a plot but a glyph renderer. And plot and figure are basically the same thing.

Comment: Thanks! This does what I was intending to do. Also thank you for correcting my terminology.