# Bokeh change selection glyph properties via widget

Tags: python, plot, bokeh, interactive

I have a bokeh plot where I want to be able to change the color of selected points to reflect whether these points (in another part of the code not in this example) will be added to or subtracted from a list of tagged data points. The problem is that I can't get the plot to use the new selection color even though the callback is being triggered and changes everything else like it should.

I'm aware of the similar question being posed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47500045/interactively-change-glyphs-in-bokeh-plot), but I'm completely new to Bokeh and can't figure out how to apply that to selection glyphs.

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.models import Circle, Dropdown, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure

N = 200
x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, N)
y = np.sin(x)
source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(x = x, y = y))

dropdown_dict = {'green': 'Add', 'red': 'Subtract'}

fig = figure(
    tools="box_select,reset",
    active_drag='box_select'
)
renderer = fig.circle(
    'x',
    'y',
    source=source,
    line_color=None,
    fill_color='black'
)
renderer.selection_glyph = Circle(fill_alpha=1, fill_color="green", line_color=None)
renderer.nonselection_glyph = Circle(fill_alpha=1, fill_color="black", line_color=None)

def dropdown_handler(event):
    color = event.item
    renderer.selection_glyph = Circle(fill_alpha=1, fill_color=color, line_color=None)
    mode = dropdown_dict[color]
    select_mode_dropdown.label = f"Selection mode: {mode}"
    print(f"Selection color changed to {color}.")

select_mode_dropdown = Dropdown(
    label='Selection mode: Add',
    menu=[(dropdown_dict[key], key) for key in dropdown_dict]
)
select_mode_dropdown.on_click(dropdown_handler)

curdoc().add_root(row(select_mode_dropdown,fig))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring out the answer. The plot doesn't change because I try to define a completely new selection glyph. Instead if I just update the fill_color property of the existing selection_glyph, the selection color changes as desired.

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.models import Circle, Dropdown, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure

N = 200
x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, N)
y = np.sin(x)
source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(x = x, y = y))

dropdown_dict = {'green': 'Add', 'red': 'Subtract'}

fig = figure(
    tools="box_select,reset",
    active_drag='box_select'
)
renderer = fig.circle(
    'x',
    'y',
    source=source,
    line_color=None,
    fill_color='black'
)
renderer.selection_glyph = Circle(fill_alpha=1, fill_color="green", line_color=None)
renderer.nonselection_glyph = Circle(fill_alpha=1, fill_color="black", line_color=None)

def dropdown_handler(event):
    color = event.item
    renderer.selection_glyph.update(fill_color=color)
    mode = dropdown_dict[color]
    select_mode_dropdown.label = f"Selection mode: {mode}"
    print(f"Selection color changed to {color}.")

select_mode_dropdown = Dropdown(
    label='Selection mode: Add',
    menu=[(dropdown_dict[key], key) for key in dropdown_dict]
)
select_mode_dropdown.on_click(dropdown_handler)

curdoc().add_root(row(select_mode_dropdown,fig))
```